# При попытке открыть файл по заданному пути выходит ошибки Could not find file "/Monkeys.json". Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Пытаюсь открыть файл, лежащий в папке проекта. При открытии приложения в эмуляторе BlueStacks, в VS выходит ошибка Could not find file "/Monkeys.json", такая же ошибка выходит при введении полного имени файла.

```
 public partial class MenuPage : ContentPage
{
    string path =  "Monkeys.json";   
    public ObservableCollection<Monkey> Monkeys { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Monkey>();
    public MenuPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }
    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        using (FileStream openStream = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            var monkeys = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Monkey[]>(openStream);
            foreach (Monkey monkey in monkeys)
            {
                Monkeys.Add(monkey);
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Вероятно потому что текущий каталог указывает не туда, куда вы думаете. Проерьте значение `Environment.CurrentDirectory`.

Comment: Пути файловой системы в Xamarin отличаются от таковых в Windows. Открывайте документацию и изучайте. [File Storage and Access with Xamarin.Android](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/). PS: `"./Monkeys.json"`?